# Are horizontal referrals in DNS allowed?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig, delegation

I've been looking into DNS quite a bit lately and currently got the following error message with the DIG command:

`BAD (HORIZONTAL) REFERRAL`

From my understanding, this is caused due to delegating a name lookup without traversing down the "DNS tree". Different to a vertical referral, which delegates down the "DNS tree", a horizontal referral delegates names like the following:

(Made-up example answer from the nameserver of the zone "google.com")

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;123.google.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns1.321.google.com.
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns2.321.google.com.
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns3.321.google.com.
```

When you ask one of the above specified nameservers, the following answer is returned:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;123.google.com. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns4.321.google.com.
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns5.321.google.com.
a.123.google.com. 7200 IN NS ns6.321.google.com.
```

This goes on and on without coming closer to the nameserver that can actually answer the request for "a.123.google.com".

Back to my question:

Are horizontal referrals generally not allowed or is only this specific case a BAD horizontal referral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizontal referrals are always bad, since they don't get you any closer to your specific query:

Let's use the example www.bar.com.

Skipping the root and TLD, we get the name servers for bar.com. 
Asking these we then get a referral to foo.com

This is in respect useless, since it didn't get us any closer to www.bar.com.

A common cause for this is to have a delegation in place for a subdomain, while still having other records in the parent zone.

For example:

foo.bar.com. is delegated somewhere, but bar.com. still contains a MX record for foo.bar.com

See the following ServerFault thread for more information:

[BIND/DNS - dig +trace = Bad Referral and Bad Horizontal Referral](https://serverfault.com/questions/803620/bind-dns-dig-trace-bad-referral-and-bad-horizontal-referral)

Comment: So is it just a bad practice or do dns resolvers generally not follow horizontal referrals?

Comment: It as far as I understand it a configuration error, so you could call it an extremely bad practice. :) Some resolvers (dig seems to be one of them) will just ignore that tree, pick a different server and start over when they hit a horizontal referral.